# Why does Firefox claim a site has a "Potential Security Risk"?

Tags: certificates, web-browser, firefox, internet

When trying to go to https://www.pfizerpapconnect.com, the Firefox web browser claims there is a "Potential Security Risk" and pops up a page recommending to not proceed.

Is there a real security issue with this site, and if so, what is it?

Comment: it does not happen to me

Comment: @Ben Hello! Maybe the detailed error message from Firefox might be useful to the readers.

Comment: The server is not properly configured. It is missing intermediate certificates. Sometimes browsers successfully work around it (Chrome), sometimes not (Firefox with fresh profile). See [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.pfizerpapconnect.com) which shows "This server's certificate chain is incomplete. Grade capped to B."